# Bash: Produce a sequence of numbers, then convert them to a string

Tags: bash, type-conversion

I need to produce a string of numbers as such: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6' going all the way from 0 to 2503 (inclusive). Using awk, I can produce a comma separated sequence of numbers as such:

```
seq -s ',' 0 2503
```

What I need to do is convert the output into one large string.

FYI, this is the required input for an argument (`--target`) in the GPAT++ tool iHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to use double quotes to wrap the result of seq command?

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sequence="$(seq -s ',' 0 2503)"
echo $sequence
```

use of $(command) returns the result of the command, and the double quote tells to bash that is a string

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure :D!

Comment: There's no point capturing the output of `seq` if all you do is immediately echo it. Just use `seq -s ',' 0 2503`. Double quotes don't create a string; they escape every character inside the string. They aren't actually necessary in this example, because `sequence=$(...)` and `sequence="$(...)"` behave identically. If you need to quote anything here, it would be in `echo "$sequence"`.